# Powershell reference variable value

Tags: powershell, for-loop, reference

i try to create a text in a variable that every time I call it takes the current value in the variable "$ name_person".

In the first round you should give:

```
Hi Victor
Hi Juan
Hi Pedro
Hi Luis
```

I'm testing with [ref] but it doesn't take it anyway.

Is there any way to do it without functions or without "replace tag"?

Thank you

```
$name_person = 'victor'

$message = "hi " + $name_person + ':'


$names = @('Juan', 'Pedro', 'Luis')


foreach ($name in $names){

    $name_person = $name
    $message 

}
```

Response:

```
hi victor:
hi victor:
hi victor:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign `ScriptBlock` value to `$message` and invoke it in your loop:

```bsh
$message =  { "hi $name_person"}
$names = @('Juan', 'Pedro', 'Luis')
foreach ($name in $names){
  $name_person = $name
  & $message 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necesary to create ScriptBlock, just use variable substitution

```
$names = @('Juan', 'Pedro', 'Luis')
foreach ($name in $names) {"hi $name"}
```